# ¿Cómo ignorar todos los archivos excepto los de una sola extensión en todos los directorios y subdirectorios?

Tags: git, gitignore

He estado mirando a través de la comunidad de stack overflow pero de las soluciones que he leído ninguna me ha funcionado. Tengo un proyecto del que solo me interesa poder hacer *git add* de absolutamente todos los archivos de extensión .cs, tanto del directorio actual, como de los subdirectorios.

Para ello, en el documento .gitignore he puesto el siguiente código.

```
*
!**/*.cs
```

Según la documentación oficial de GIT, el **/ permite hacer referencia a todos los archivos de todos los subdirectorios, y el ! permite negar su ignoración. He probado poner solo **/*.cs y ahí me ignora los archivos cs de todos los directorios, pero al juntarlo con ! ya no funciona.

- Mi versión de GIT es 2.25.1.windows.1.

Pd: Cada vez que lo intentaba con diferentes códigos borraba lo añadido con

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución que se me ocurre es que mediante el comando `git add` indiques exactamente que archivos deseas hacerles `commit` a través de su extensión del modo siguiente:

Tenemos una carpeta con 4 archivos de esta forma:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\pruebas>git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        index.html
        index.php
        index2.html
        index2.php

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Como observamos tenemos 4 archivos, 2 con extensión .php y 2 con extensión .html; deseamos mover solamente los de la primera.

Entonces ejecutamos el comando:

```
git add *.php
```

Si ahora revisamos el estado con:

```
git status
```

Veremos que al stage se movieron:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\pruebas>git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   index.php
        new file:   index2.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        index.html
        index2.html
```

Como puedes observar estan esperando para hacerles `commit` solo aquellos archivos con coincidieron con la extensión marcada

Entonces si finalizamos el envío de los archivos y posteriormente revisamos el estado obtendremos un resultado como el siguiente:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\pruebas>git commit -m "Solo los de php"
[master (root-commit) 2f4a705] Solo los de php
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 index.php
 create mode 100644 index2.php

C:\Users\user\Desktop\pruebas>git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        index.html
        index2.html

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

- Evitamos el uso del comando `git add all/.` ya que esto ignoraría el uso de la extensión y añadiría todos los archivos
- Tal vez deberás repetir esta secuencia por cada carpeta *(lo cual seguramente no ofrece la mejor de la formas de hacerlo)*

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu implicación. Pero necesito que sea en el .gitignore. Porque además necesito descartar unos archivos .cs con un nombre específico. Lo que se me alargaría cada vez que tenga que hacer git add. Por eso quiero que quede en  el gitignore para hacer luego solo git add -A.

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene de la siguiente observación, copiada de la documentación en https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore (la traducción y la negrita son mías):

> Un prefijo opcional "!" niega el patrón; cualquier fichero que encaje y que hubiera sido excluído por un patrón previo, será incluido de nuevo. **No es posible re-incluir un fichero si un directorio padre de ese fichero ha sido excluido**.

Debido a que comienzas con el patrón `*`, eso excluye todos los ficheros **y directorios**, por lo que ya no es posible re-incluir ningún csv después porque sus directorios padres fueron excluidos.

Una solución que se me ocurre es el siguiente `.gitignore`:

```
*
!*/
!**/*.csv
```

La primera regla excluye todo, ficheros y carpetas. La segunda regla vuelve a incluir las carpetas. De este modo la tercera regla ya puede funcionar, re-incluyendo los csv.

PD: Para hacer pruebas, en vez de añadir y luego volver a sacar, puedes usar la opción `-n` del comando `add`, que no añade nada en realidad pero te muestra lo que añadiría. Ej: `git add -A -n`